# handle deleted message by user in telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Is there any way that can handle deleted message by user in one-to-one chat or groups that bot is member of it ?
there is method for edited message update but not for deleted message .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. There is no way to track whether messages have been deleted or not.

Comment: really ?! so :(

Comment: Unfortunately :(

Comment: This is sad ! :<

Comment: I would recommend asking @BotSupport to implement this. If enough people ask, they have to listen

Comment: There is actually:
https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateDeleteMessages

Answer (score 0):

The pyrogram have *DeletedMessagesHandler / @Client.on_deleted_messages()*. If used as Userbot, It handles in all chat groups channels. I failed to filter. Maybe it will work in a bot

Comment: Returns only msg_id

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an event update from the official API docs:
https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateDeleteMessages

I had the very same problem, 'cause no framework seems to manage this event. I solved by using directly the official Telegam libraries [TDLibs](https://github.com/tdlib/td) with a JS wrapper ([TDL](https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl) in this case).
Here it is a simple and working code:

```js
import {Client} from 'tdl'
import {TDLib} from 'tdl-tdlib-addon'
import {getTdjson} from 'prebuilt-tdlib'


// Start bot
const client = new Client(new TDLib(getTdjson()), {
  apiHash: YOUR_TELEGRAM_API_HASH,
  apiId: YOUR_TELEGRAM_API_ID
})
await client.loginAsBot(YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)


// Manage updates
client.on('update', function(update) {
    // On deleted message(s) event
    if (update._ === 'updateDeleteMessages') {
        return yourHandlerFunction()
    }

    // If Other updates, do other stuff ...
})


// Print errors
client.on('error', console.error)
```